# How can I delay an action until after the $apply is finished?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given this code:

```
   <body ng-keydown="key($event);">

   $scope.key = function ($event) {
       if (key == 13) {
           document.getElementById("aButton").click();
       }
   }
```

When I run the code I am getting a message saying there is:

```
   $apply already in progress
```

Can someone give me some advice on how I can fix my problem.

Comment: Seems like we need to see more code here. Are you interfacing from a non-Angular event?

Comment: It's all AngularJS.  The keydown is activated when I click the ENTER key on the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$timeout`

```
$scope.key = function ($event) {
       if ($event.which == 13) {
           $timeout(function(){
              document.getElementById("aButton").click();
           })
       }
   }
```

Comment: I will try this now. Can you explain to me what the $timeout is doing ? In my code I get a message saying cannot find $timeout

Comment: $timeout is like settimeout function provided by the browser. It will delay the execution of the function provided to it. For more details - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout